# How can I use passportjs and reactjs together?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I have 3 views, (Home, signup, login)made in reactJs, I want to use passport in my project but I dont know how to do it, I have passport configurated and it url is working.

What can I do to manage the session and the user data like we do in ejs or jade?

Answer (score 10):

- Use componentDidMount/useEffect to get authentication status. Set status in react state.
- If not authenticated, Show the link to Login/Signup page or redirect.
- If authenticated, you can return additional protected data or show the link to the protected page.(When showing private data, check authentication status on every page by using componentDidMount/useEffect)

Client-side example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/checkAuthentication')
      .then(res => {
        setLoggedIn(res.data.authenticated);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoggedIn(false)
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loggedIn ? (
        <p>Login success</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Link to="/signup">
           Signup
          </Link>
          <Link to="/login">
            Login
          </Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Server-side example (req.user must be populated if you set up passport)

```
app.get("/checkAuthentication", (req, res) => {
  const authenticated: boolean = typeof req.user !== 'undefined'

  res.status(200).json({
    authenticated,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to create a middleware function where put the code

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) { 
    return next() 
  } else {
    res.redirect('/')
  }
}
```

and then use in a router

```
app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  // here return some data
})
```

From React probably you have to do a fetch request

```
fetch('https://your_url/account', {
  credentials: 'include'  
})
```

Something like this, you have to make ajax request to the server or by using socket.io or websockets

Answer (score 4):

You can Use passport.js with node.js and also can use jsonwebtoken ,i personally use that very usefull simple to code and pretty secure and easily can use to frontend with react or any other frontend framework . The best thing is 
**backend :-> node.js + passport.js + jsonwebtoken
frontend :-> react/ any other framework + redux** 
it works really awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need passport, but in a backend environment with users authentication. Something with node.js+express.js+passport+someDB.

Probably a bit more that what you're asking for, but you can use [feathersjs](https://feathersjs.com/) that comes with these built in modules.

With [FeathersCli](https://github.com/feathersjs/cli) you get user/pass authentication with JWToken in no time by running (after installed):
`feathers generate app` then `feathers generate authentication`

Answer (score 0):

MERN stack - things that you need to take care of:

- express-session
- passportjs

As express-session and passport are middleware they intercept your `req` object and add different objects related to the user and session into it. Make sure you have implemented express-session first and then go for the `passportjs`.
You will need `CORS` so add it before your routes:

```
const options = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost:3001",
  methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
};
app.use(cors(options));
```

For your frontend part  make sure that you are passing your credentials and headers for example I use `axios` for this hence it look like this :

```
const res = await axios.get(url, {
    withCredentials: "true",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

Packages initialization is also crucial if you end up defining a few packages before others ( ex: passport before express-session) you will face issues.